# Replace subset of MySQL records

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database called `ice_cream` with three tables, `users`, `flavors`, and `favorites`. Each record in `favorites` has a reference to a user and a flavor, and a user is able to have multiple ice cream flavors.

I'm trying to write a transaction to completely replace a user's favorites with another set of favorites. For example, when the API accepts

```
PUT /user/100/favorites

{ 
  "flavors": {
    "2": { "stars": 2 },
    "3": { "stars": 5, "comments": "Changed my life" },
    "18": { "stars": 4, "comments": " " },
    "24": { "stars": 4 }
  }
}
```

The `favorites` table should change from

```
| id  | user_id | flavor_id | stars | comments           |
| --- | ------- | --------- | ----- | ------------------ |
| 200 | 100     | 2         | 2     | Tastes OK          |
| 201 | 100     | 4         | 3     |                    |
| 202 | 100     | 5         | 3     |                    |
```

To

```
| id  | user_id | flavor_id | stars | comments           |
| --- | ------- | --------- | ----- | ------------------ |
| 200 | 100     | 2         | 2     |                    |
| 201 | 100     | 3         | 5     | Changed my life    |
| 203 | 100     | 18        | 4     |                  |
| 204 | 100     | 24        | 4     |                    |
```

What's the most efficient set of statements to accomplish this?

Points to consider:

- I'm not concerned with keeping primary ids consistent.
- The users are really into the small-batch craft ice cream scene and will usually replace about 5000 records each transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case the most efficient  set of statements is delete  and insert

```
delete from flavors
where user_id =100;
```

and a loop server side  for insert  the new values or a batch insert with all the values  in repated values rows

```
insert into flavors ( user_id, flavor_id, stars , comments ) 
values (  100,2 ,2 null), 
      (100, 3, 5 , 'Changed my life'), 
      (100 ,18,4 ,   ),
       (100 , 24 ,4 , null)
```